# The variable($product.id_product) is not passed to function :( (Prestahop)

Tags: php, function, smarty, prestashop

Is a function that is called in product-list.php.

```
{mycat id_product_my=$product.id_product}
```

In this form, write a line above, the `variable($product.id_product)` is not passed to function:

```
{$product.id_product}
```

returns right result as id.

```
{mycat id_product_my=15}
```

returns right result as categories of product with id(15).

What’s wrong?

————————————————————————————————————————————

php funct:

```
function smarty_compiler_mycat($params, &$smarty) {

    $id_product_my = $params[‘id_product_my’];

    $ret = “”;

    if ($row = Db::getInstance(PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE)->ExecuteS(’
        SELECT cl.`name` FROM `’.DB_PREFIX.‘category_lang` cl 
        LEFT JOIN `’.DB_PREFIX.‘category_product` cp ON cl.`id_category` = cp.`id_category` 
        WHERE cp.`id_product` = ‘.(int)$id_product_my) )
            foreach ($row as $val) {
                $ret .= $val[‘name’].” “;
            }

    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don`t know that i understand correct your prob!

if u want call a function in tpl file u must call like this :

```
{parameter1|functionName:parameter2:parameter3}
```

Comment: Thank you all!
it was necessary to replace smarty_compiler_mycat on smarty_function_mycat.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it a compiler function? Just make it a regular runtime function. Change the function name to `smarty_function_mycat`, keep the same arguments, change the filename to `function.mycat.php`.

As a matter of test/debug, you could `var_dump($params)` within the function to see what's actually in the `$product.id_product` you pass.